# How to wrapping function in Python like in JavaScript?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a new function that doing print, only if `Debug=True`. This how I'm doing it in JavaScript:

```
function log(...args) {
    if (debug) console.log.apply(null,args)
}
```

or

```
 function log() {
        if (debug) console.log.apply(null,arguments)
    }
```

How I can do similar things in Python?

The question: How to pass all the arguments I'm getting in Python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference call function with asterisk parameter and without](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197586/difference-call-function-with-asterisk-parameter-and-without)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variable arguments and variable keyword arguments:

```
# assuming debug is a global variable initialized as either True or False
def log(*args, **kwargs):
    if debug:
        print(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question specifically, something like the following should help you:

```
def log(**kwargs):
    if kwargs.get("debug") == True:
        print "{}".format(kwargs)
```

In particular, you can read more about `*args` and `**kwargs` - [this SO question is an excellent start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)